# sorting an array where the second property may be nonexistent

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I need to sort a table for an Angular project.  The catch is that for some of the values in the table, I need to sort by a direct property of the objects in the array, but for others I need to sort by a child of that direct property.

For example, I have `associate.lastname` for one column and `associate.client.name` for another column.  I'm trying to do all of this in one method and I've got a working method in TypeScript.

This is the `sortBy` method in my component's class:

```js
sortBy(option: SortOption, sortedBy: string) {
    const props = option.split('.');
    const parent = props[0];
    const child = props[1];
    const asc = this[sortedBy];
    if(!child) {
        this.associates.sort((associateA, associateB)=> {
            if (associateA[parent] < associateB[parent]) {
                return asc === true ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (associateB[parent] < associateA[parent]) {
                return asc === true ? 1 : -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.associates.sort((associateA, associateB)=> {
            if (associateA[parent][child] < associateB[parent][child]) {
                return asc === true ? -1 : 1;
            } else if (associateB[parent][child] < associateA[parent][child]) {
                return asc === true ? 1 : -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
      }
      this[sortedBy] = !this[sortedBy]
}
```

`SortOption` is an enum, and the value may or may not have a `.` in it.  I split on that period to get the parent and child properties, and then sort the array based on whether the parent or the child exists.

Now what I'm wondering is if there's a better, drier, way to do this.  You'll notice the code in both the if and the else statement are almost exactly the same, with the exception of the child property being used or not, but I can't think of a cleaner way to do this.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to extract a sorting key function:

```
let sortingKey: (associate: any) => number;  // or some other type, depends on your code
if (child) {
    sortingKey = (associate) => associate[parent][child];
} else {
    sortingKey = (associate) => associate[parent];
}
```

After that you will be able to simply write:

```
this.associates.sort((associateA, associateB)=> {
    if (sortingKey(associateA) < sortingKey(associateB)) {
        return asc === true ? -1 : 1;
    } else if (sortingKey(associateB) < sortingKey(associateA)) {
        return asc === true ? 1 : -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Perfect.  Was beating myself trying to find a way to factor it out into a function, wasn't seeing it.  Thanks.